# where does pyplot define the number of levels

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, colorbar, contourf

I'm trying to understand how levels, values, boundaries are created in the contourf-toolchain.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

t=np.array([[-5,0,5,0,0,0],[0,0,5,0,0,0],[0,0,5,0,0,0],[5,5.2,10,5,5,0],
            [0,0,5,0,0,0]], dtype=np.double)
print ("print as is")
print (t)
print ("appearing in a contourf as:")
print (np.flipud((t)))
# assuming indices: array[x,y]
# value 10 supposed to be at 0,0
# contourf's pos. x-axis is pointing up!! 
xmin, xmax=-2, 3
ymin, ymax=-3, 1

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)
ax0 = axs[0]
ax1 = axs[1]

# plot and add colorbar
set0 = ax0.contourf(t, extent=(xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax), cmap="brg")

#colorbar with coarse steps
cba = plt.colorbar(set0,ax=ax0)
# # This makes the colorbar "appear continuos"
# cba.boundaries=None
# cba.values = None
set0.changed()

# define colorbar and then plot
cNorm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=np.min(t), vmax=np.max(t))
sm = mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(cNorm, cmap="brg")
cbb = plt.colorbar(sm,ax=ax1)

set1 = ax1.contourf(t, extent=(ymin,ymax,xmin,xmax), cmap="brg")

plt.show()
print("left .boundaries: {:s}".format(str(cba.boundaries)))
print("left ._boundaries: {:s}".format(str(cba._boundaries)))
print("right .boundaries: {:s}".format(str(cbb.boundaries)))
print("right len(._boundaries): {:s}".format(str(len(cbb._boundaries))))
```

For the left plot the colorbar has 9 boundaries and 8 discrete color values for the right one there are 257 boundaries.
I did a couple of vars(...) and dir(...) on the various objects. Where is decision made on the amount of boundaries and values made?
What is the deviation of the right plots colorbar creation from the default behaviour?

Comment: The left colorbar gets its number of values from the contourplot which tries to determine a "nice" number of levels for the data range. The right plot is unchanged, only the colorbar is mapped differently. But by using a colormap like `brg`, you import the standard number of colors for a matplotlib colormap, i.e., 256. If you imported it differently, e.g., with `sm = mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(cNorm, cmap=mpl.cm.get_cmap('Blues', 3))`, you would get a different number of levels for the colorbar. But again, given your code, you only change the appearance of the colorbar,.

Comment: The plots are the same intentionally. This ist just about the colorbar. So the plt.colorbar-call for the left plot adopts the number of levels from the contourf and the right plot uses the default from the colormap. None of each is controlled from the calling code. Is there a simple way to define the number of levels?

Comment: Both of them are defined by the calling code. The left by the number of [levels in contourf](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contourf.html) and the right by the number of colors defined by [your colormap](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormap-manipulation.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-colors-colormap-manipulation-py). They just happened to fall back to default values in both cases because you did not specify them.